# Round and concatenate an abbreviation in excel

Tags: excel, google-sheets, rounding, concatenation

I am trying to format the market cap of companies in excel to look like google- ie,

```
15.46B 
456.78M
```

In a google spreadsheet I call the function =GoogleFinance(A2, "MarketCap") and receive the data. For instance ACMP with a market cap of 7,916,327,249.00.

Then I conditionally divide  by =IF(E2>1000000000,E2/1000000000,E2/1000000) to get the number in a decimal form.  If marketcap is over a billion then it divides by a bil.  If it is under then i divide by a mil.

Now it is 7.916327249.  I have that to 7.92.  Lastly I try to concateinate with
=IF(E2>1000000000,CONCAT(F2," B"),CONCAT(F2," M")) but it undoes the rounding and  I get 
7.916327249B.  Any easy way around this? thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, use the TEXT function!

```
=IF(E2>1000000000,CONCAT(TEXT(F2,"0.00")," B"),CONCAT(TEXT(F2,"0.00")," M"))
```

Answer (score 0):

In Excel this can be done in one step (don't know about Google Docs):

```
=IF(E1>1000000000,TEXT(E1,"0.00,,,")&" B",TEXT(E1,"0.00,,")&" M")
```

You could even, I assume, embed the GoogleFinance() function in this formula.

In Excel you can create the following as a **Custom Format** for E1:

```
[>=1000000000]0.00,,," B";[>100000000]0.00,," M"
```

this has the advantage that the value remains a number, rather than text, and it all happens for a single cell.

Comment: I look into simplifying the steps soon, the only problem is the computer I'm on is XP and it uses excel 2003 so it was just easier to do on a doc rather than write scripts.

Comment: Why did you put the commas? They seem to make the value to `0.00` no matter what the value in E1 for me.

Comment: It works for me (in Excel) if I enter the original value 7,916,327,249.00 in E1, or reduce it to millions. The commas effectively *discard* sequences of three-zeroes.